# Bokeh: CustomJS Error - Missing BokehJS library

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

I'm trying to make a TextAreaInput to scroll-down automatically with every text update, when I tried to used CustomJS, I found this error on the browser generated script:

```
Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing
```

and this error on the browser console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

and

```
[bokeh] Failed to repull session TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

Although, I reduced the javascript code to "nothing", the same error appears.
Here's the code snippet

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextAreaInput
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

class projectdata:
    def __init__(self, doc):
        self.textarea = TextAreaInput(value="XER file contents will show here!", rows = 10, name="textarea", css_classes=["mytext"])
        callback = CustomJS(args=dict(text=self.textarea),code="""""")
        self.textarea.js_on_change('scroll', callback)
```

Python: 3.7.3,
Bokeh: 1.3.4,
Browser: Chrome

Thanks

Comment: The issue is not in that snippet. The issue is in however you are generating output, so more information is needed.

Comment: My original code contains many widgets and OnClick handlers, all works fine, the error only appeared when I tried to use the CustomJS callback, see, there’s no JavaScript code, so maybe the error is in the way I invoke the TextAreaInput, or there’s a problem with the preloaded BokehJS files, I work with Bokeh 1.3.4 and it’s currently 1.4, I will make a test for CustomJS callback on Button click, if I get the same error then the problem is not the widgets

Comment: If you are saying that you are using one version of Python Bokeh and a different bokehjs version is 100% unsupported. The python/js versions absolutely must match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

After trials, I found the error cause was "scroll" in the line

```
self.textarea.js_on_change('scroll', callback)
```

the correct name should be "value"

```
self.textarea.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

after that small change, all works fine, but still working on the automatic scroll for TextArea

Answer (score -2):

Well the first error is telling you that you do not have https://pypi.org/project/bokeh/

Comment: It's not saying that. It's saying the page being rendered does not properly load the *JavaScript* BokehJS library.